# Using paperjs on a vuejs project based on SFC

Tags: vue.js, paperjs

I have a vuejs project based on single file components. I want to add a canvas and dinamically draw things with paperjs, based on my component data. What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self response. A working SFC.

```html
<template>
    <canvas resize id="main-canvas">{{circle_diameter}}</canvas>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import paper from 'paper'
export default {
    data: () => ({ x: 20, y: 20 }),
    props: ['circle_diameter'],
    methods: {
        updateDrawing() {
            paper.setup(document.getElementById('main-canvas'))
            // Now, draw your things based on component state.
            const point = new paper.Point(this.x, this.y)
            const circle = new paper.Path.Circle(point, this.circle_diameter/2)
            circle.fillColor = 'grey'
            circle.strokeColor = 'black'
        },
    },
    updated() {
        this.updateDrawing()
    },
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Since paperjs will render outside vue scope, drawing is not reactive until you place `{{circle_diameter}}` into the canvas html tags. This way, you force Vue to call update() each time a prop changes.